# Why do iOS SpriteKit scene / view coordinates differ between iOS 7.1 and iOS 8?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios8

I am exploring the iOS 8 beta version of SpriteKit, with my project's deployment target set to iOS 7 so I can test on my iPad Air running the released iOS 7.1.

I have found that the coordinates between my `SKScene` and its `SKView` are not consistent between the simulator (running iOS 8) and my device (running iOS 7.1). Here is the code I've used to isolate the inconsistency:

Starting with the iOS SpriteKit game template, I've modified the settings so that only **Landscape Right** orientation is supported and I've added the following code to the `GameScene` class:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    …

    var scaleFromView: CGPoint!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
        label.text = "Hello, World!";
        label.fontSize = 65;
        label.position = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.0);
        label.zPosition = -1.0

        let referencePt = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        var viewPt = convertPointToView(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        viewPt = viewPt + referencePt
        let scenePt = convertPointFromView(viewPt)
        scaleFromView = scenePt / referencePt
        println("  view.bounds is \(view.bounds)")
        println("   scene.size is \(scene.size)")
        println("scaleFromView is \(scaleFromView)")

        world.addChild(label)
    }

    …
```

Note this uses some operators I've defined for working with `CGPoint`:

```
@infix func + (a: CGPoint, b: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: a.x + b.x, y: a.y + b.y)
}

@infix func - (a: CGPoint, b: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: a.x - b.x, y: a.y - b.y)
}

@infix func * (a: CGPoint, b: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: a.x * b.x, y: a.y * b.y)
}

@infix func / (a: CGPoint, b: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: a.x / b.x, y: a.y / b.y)
}
```

When run under *any* of the iOS 8 simulators, including the iPad Air simulation, the `println` statement logs (as I would expect given the scene and view bounds settings):

```
  view.bounds is (0.0,0.0,1024.0,768.0)
   scene.size is (1024.0,768.0)
scaleFromView is (1.0,-1.0)
```

But when I run it on my device, I get:

```
  view.bounds is (0.0,0.0,768.0,1024.0)
   scene.size is (1024.0,768.0)
scaleFromView is (0.75,-0.75)
```

Thus it seems the view does not properly reflect that it's in landscape orientation. **Why is this happening?**

*PS: I've downloaded the iOS 7.1 simulators and can now report that they behave consistently with the device. That is, this seems to be a bug / feature of iOS 7.1.*

Comment: you mean the inconsistency exists in iOS 8, not 7.1, right? Typically that mixup of coords happens when the skview is created in viewDidLoad rather than viewWillLayoutSubviews but not sure how this applies to swift/ios 8

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: Sorry I wasn't clear. The inconsistency occurs on iOS 7.1, but *not* on iOS 8. I'm using the SpriteKit game template from the Xcode 6 beta, so the `SKView` is created when the nib is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading and installing the **iOS 7.1** simulators, I was able to determine that they behave consistently with the device. That is, they too report `view.bounds` reflecting portrait rather than landscape mode, even though (or perhaps *because*) my app is landscape-only.

This seems to be a bug / feature of **iOS 7.1**.